# RedirectMatch 301 with a Wildcard (htaccess)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Anyone know how to redirect from one location to another in the WordPress .htaccess file using a wildcard?

This redirects **example.com/files/** to **example.com/wp-content/uploads/**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /files/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1
```

I need some that redirects **example.com/files/** to **example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/121/**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /files/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/sites/.*/$1
```

The # 121 was just an example. The way it works is each Wordpress Multisite blog is identified by a #. Starting from 1 and up.

Comment: You cannot use wildcard on right hand side of the rule.

Comment: Also if you have multiple directories like `123`, `567` and `789` in `sites` sub directory then where should redirection be made?